# WCF Error Handler Exception Logging

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I use `IErrorHandler` in my project for handle exceptions.

But how can i log incoming method parameter with exception.
I want to get Request parameter for logging.

Sample Method:

```
public Response GetData(Request request) {
    return new Response();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could get the request message like this:

```
Message requestMessage = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
```

What I do usually is to log the entire request XML.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. The native WCF logger will capture all requests & responses when set to verbose however, these files tend to get real big, real quick.
2. Use log4net (search google to download)

   private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));

   ```
   public class MyClass
   ```

   {
       ...

   ```
   public Foo DoSomething(string arg)
   {
       try
       {
          //do something
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
          log.error(string.format("{0} Arguements: {1}", e.Tostring(), arg);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: This does not answer how to log a request in a class that implements IErrorHandler to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have such information in `IErrorHandler` - you can only parse raw message in `ProvideFault` method.

You can try to use another approach - implement custom `IOperationInvoker` and in `Invoke` method do something like:

```
// Just synchronous implementation - for asynchronous handle InvokeBegin and InvokeEnd
public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
{
  try
  {
    // Run common invoker - you will create new Invoker as decorator for existing one.
    return innerInvoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, outputs);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    // Handle error here
  }
}
```

Operation invoker is responsible for selection correct operation in service and ivoke it. It is just idea - I haven't tested it.